# SQl Server 2012 LocalDb Shared Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, localdb

I am considering adding LocalDB for data storage to my application.

Background:

1) My Application has 2 parts.
a. A Desktop Client. (Running Under the user that logged into the computer)
b. NT Service. (Running as Local System)

NT Service:
1) Make web service calls to our back end server for client specific settings and configuration options.
2) Upload client created records.

Desktop App: 
1) Load the settings downloaded by the NT Service and run according to those settings.
2) Create client records.

LocalDB seem like a good fit here but can both of these items access the LOCALDB at the same time? After some investigation online it looks like a LOCALDB shared instance may be possible. However does that mean the NT Service would have to keep the LOCALDB connection alive all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having done a very similar deployment to what you have described, yes this can be done. However I would strongly advise against it.

Some thoughts:

1. LocalDB '**instances**' require the user profile be loaded. The only use profile that is always loaded is Local System aka the **NT Authority\SYSTEM** account.
2. Only the owner of the '**instance**' can start or stop it. The '**automagic**' instance can be set to ignore the auto-showdown timeout, but it still has to be started atleast once. I solved this by creating a windows task that launched a bootstrapper that shelled out '*sqllocaldb start v11.0*' on boot. Windows Tasks execute with '**Below Normal**' process priority so the launched bootstrapper actually boosted the SQLEnv.exe priority to high for my use case.
3. Assuming you go with **NT Authority\SYSTEM** being the instance profile, using something like SQL Management Studio would likely require PsExec on the system. This is a security risk because it gives you interactive access to a proccess that runs as Local System. Don't do it.
4. We used groups for access to our client part so we grant access for those groups to the actual database/instance. Without that it is damn near impossible to grant new users access to the instance/database.

Do you really need a database or could the thick client write out a file to a specific location for each record that the service then inspects(or builds a buffer) and sends on its way?

Another alternative is to remove the NT Service and make its functionality the a part of the Client start up process. Why have a long running process that constantly checks for config changes and only pushes data if the user is actively using the system? Assuming you don't have requirements/an existing system.

Comment: I have decided against this. I am going to go the route of using SQL CE instead. I have built a IPC layer for the client to communicate with the NT Service.